# About the density of a subqpace of $L^2$?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

We all know that $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Now, is the space $\{f\in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}):f(a)=0\}$ (where $a\in\mathbb{R}$) still dense in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$?

Thanks a lot!

Math.

Comment: Sure it is dense in $L^2((-\infty,a-\epsilon)\cup (a+\epsilon,\infty))$ which is dense in $L^2(\Bbb{R})$